# Event getting triggered multiple times on scroll event handler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

While I was adding code to scroll event of a panel in c#, I found a strange behavior.

I have added a panel and inside the panel (auto-Scroll = true) there is a groupbox.

As shown below clicking the scroll moves scroll bar to a small distance.

[image]

At the same time, when I add a message box in the event to display a notification that a scroll has taken place, multiple message box are popping out.

[image]

Why is that?

I have already planned to add some logic when scrolling, but if it occurs multiple times then how it could be possible?

Here is the event handler:

```
private void panel1_Scroll_1(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ScrollBar is clicked");
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220691/track-bar-only-fire-event-on-final-value-not-ever-time-value-changes

Comment: but that is explained for a trackbar..

Comment: Similar handling is required. You cannot stop it firing many times. You should handle it appropriately in a similar way that is explained in that thread.

Comment: thank you @CharithJ,but one more question..then why does the pic1 showed like that ?

Comment: Because your event has been executed multiple times while scroll bar poistion is being changed.

Comment: but the movement of scroll was limited in first pic ?..If we add some event only it triggers multiple time ? correct me if im wrong..

Answer (score 4):

This is just how scroll event works, it fires many times while the panel is scrolling.

Try [ScrollEventArgs.Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrolleventtype(v=vs.85).aspx) `EndScroll` which should be the last scroll event.

```
  private void panel1_Scroll_1(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.EndScroll)
            MessageBox.Show("ScrollBar is clicked");
    }
```

If above doesn't help for your case you will need to handle those multiple events by using one of approaches explains in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220691/track-bar-only-fire-event-on-final-value-not-ever-time-value-changes).

Comment: Message box is not displayed here !

Comment: Did you click or scrolled using mouse? Doesn't it work in both cases?

Comment: i clicked once..scroll too not popping message box out

Comment: actually i cannot scroll using scroll button in mouse..but can move by dragging scroll bar..but eventually no pop ups

Comment: Put a breakpoint there and see what you get for the e.Type? –

Comment: e.Type = SmallIncrement

Comment: Theoritically, you should receive many events with SmallIncrements and at the end you should receive EndScroll. This is strange. Btw, what are you tring to do?

Comment: thank you charith ..i was trying to add some events in scroll..and just tested with a message box which showed me this behavior